# Keep part of text between strings using regex

Tags: python, regex

Using the following code I have extracted a transcripted Interview from a pdf:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
text = extract_text(f"C:/Users/User/Desktop/Interview1.pdf")
```

The general structure of a transcript looks like this (\n are included on purpose as these might be one reason why my code doesn't work):

> CHRIS BACON, CEO COMMERCIAL METALS COMPANY: bla bla bla...
>
> BARBARA SMITH, SVP AND CFO, COMMERCIAL METALS COMPANY: I agree with Chris Bacon, bla bla bla bla....
>
> \nJOSEPH  ALVARADO:  Bla bla bla bla....

**GOAL**
As you can see there are multiple people being interviewed and I am only interested in the transcripted text of a specific person whereas the start of a person's text is always indicated with the person's name (uppercase) sometimes followed by their position in the company and always ends with a colon ":" before the start of the text.

I tried the following code to extract the text of Barbara Smith which unfortunately doesn't return anything:

```
Smith_text = re.findall(r'SMITH(.*):(.*):', text)
```

I am not very familiar with regex and would appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Comment: As per anubhava - you have one too many colons: Should be something like this: `(.*\bSMITH)(.*):(.*)` - see here: https://regex101.com/r/rLhyrJ/1

Comment: Does `re.findall(r'\bSMITH\b[^:]*:(.*(?:\n.+)*)', text)` help?

Comment: There should only be one colon after the desired name.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
strr = """CHRIS BACON, CEO COMMERCIAL METALS COMPANY: bla bla bla...\nBARBARA SMITH, SVP AND CFO, COMMERCIAL METALS COMPANY: I agree with Chris Bacon, bla bla bla bla....\nJOSEPH ALVARADO: Bla bla bla bla...."""

Smith_text = re.findall(r'(?<=SMITH)(.*)(?=\n)', strr)
```